# How to add text + icon to HTML table row element in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, html-table

I am trying to update an HTML table row element with a text and icon. This is what I have tried so far:

```
const cell = document.getElementById("cellID");
```

`if (true) {
   cell.innerHTML = {someText} {<i className="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-fw" />}
}`

Here, `cell` is a cell in the the HTML table. For example, `<td id="someId">some text</td>`,
I can update the text easily with `cell.textContent = 'newText'` but it does not work when I try to add an icon next to the text.
It does not work. How can I add the icon with the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with template literals

```
   if (true) { 
        cell.innerHTML = `${someText} <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-fw" />`
   }
```

Comment: Yes, I just tried. It shows `some text [object Object]`.

Comment: I got it to work. There is a slight change from what you recommended.

`if (true) { cell.innerHTML = `${someText} <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-fw" />`
   }`

Comment: I didn’t get the fix you did

Comment: if (true) {
cell.innerHTML = `'${someText} <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-fw" />'`
}

I just used the icon element as a string in the innerHTML. Also, replaced 'className' with 'class'. Hope I explained it better now.

Comment: Yes. I thought of pointing the same. As we are directly manipulating them DOM element we have to change it to class instead of className to icon.